# TextTrimming fails with Custom fonts

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, ellipsis, custom-font, texttrimming

Text trimming is not working for custom font. Any clues on how to fix that?

```
<TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="i want to put a really long text " TextAlignment="Center" TextTrimming ="WordEllipsis" Foreground="#FFE89192"  Width="350"/>
```

Comment: it's working, set width property a lit a bit lower and see for yourself

Comment: @SeeSharp I found the issue, I'm using a custom font. Ellipsis works in the default one but not the custom font. Any clues for that?

Comment: sorry but i can't recreate your problem